# How to manage commons pages in page object pattern

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pageobjects

Using page object pattern I was creating a class for each page. Then I realized some pages have similar css classes, I was repeating too much code.
Example: 
**BasePage** = all the pages inherit from him (where the driver and waits are setted)
**Page1, Page2, Page3** = all of them have similar propertiers, so I grouped them in one class called
commonPage

Using the good practice of pageObjetcs in the commonPage, I divided in other 3 pages (so they can keep smaller): *CommonPage_Header*, *CommonPage_Menu* and *CommonPage_List*.

The problem is that, eg, page1 can't inherit from CommonPage_Header, CommonPage_Menu and CommonPage_Header. How can I manage this situation? I've already tried using abstract classes and interfaces.

What I need is that each page inherits from *commonPage_Header*, *commonPage_Menu* and *commonPage_List* with their any particular property

Note: Some of these 'particular properties' are methods with bodies, that's why I don't intend to use interfaces

````
public class BasePage(){
 //browsers and timeouts
}

public abstract class CommonPage_Header extends BasePage {
     public PanelHeader(WebDriver driver) {
            super(driver);
        }
//similar methods
}

public class Page1 extends CommonPage_Header {
//overwriting some methods of CommonPage_Header, but setting some specification for the page 1
//The problem: I need to use methods of CommonPage_Menu and CommonPage_List too :(
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Why inherit?

Put in use `is-a`, `has-a` relationship, avoid inheritance, use composition.
Think to the header, menu as components and inject them in the page objects using inheritance.

For example I would not put header, menu in each page object that ui suggest.

Why not have a single general page object that has these common components instead of having them in all the page objects?
Use a structure that is easy to understand for you, think high level first > define > refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to inherit in your page. Please create a page where other page objects are variables like

```
Page 1 Object has
CommonHeader ch1 =new CommonHeader
CommonFooter ch2-=new CommonFooter
```

Comment: do you mean composition? Could you please give more details?